# AngularJS: Pass data from Controller to Service

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2013

First: [Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/s4ldUjcnkamSc3lLEILd).

Currently I am trying to build a basic sign-up app with AngularJS hosted on a SharePoint site. I am pulling the current user data with a factory like so:

```
app.factory('Data', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
        getCurrentUser: function (complete, failure) {
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/currentUser",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    complete(data.d);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    failure(data);
                }
            });
        }
```

I then use a controller to assign the results (in this case the user Title) to a value:

```
app.controller('IndexCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
    Data.getCurrentUser(function (user) {
        CurrentUser = user.Title;
    });
```

Now, the issue I am having is that the value of `CurrentUser` is not usable in all parts of the factory. Right now, everything is in one factory and one controller. So, I can use `CurrentUser` to create a new appointment like this:

```
app.factory('Data', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
        updateAppointment: function (appointment) {
            var Title = appointment.Title;
            var Appointment = appointment.Appointment;
            var CurrentSpots = appointment.Openings;
            var Id = appointment.Id;

            // Create new Reservations list item
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('SharePointList')/Items",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    "__metadata": { type: "SP.Data.SharePointListItem" },
                    Title: Title,
                    Appointment: Appointment,
                    Colleague: CurrentUser,
                    AppointmentId: Id
                }),
                headers: { 
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                },
                failure: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var response = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);
                    var message = response ? response.error.message.value : textStatus;
                    alert("Error: " + message);
                }
            });
```

But I cannot seem to use it when I try to do a query including that `CurrentUser` value in something like this:

```
app.factory('Data', function ($http, $log) {
    return {
        getCurrentAppointment: function (successCallback) {
            $http({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('SharePointList')/Items?$filter=User eq '" + CurrentUser + "'",
                method: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                async: "true",
                headers: { 
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                }
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                successCallback(data.d.results);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                $log.warn(data, status, headers, config);
            });
        }
```

No matter what I've tried, it consistently gives me an `undefined` return for that CurrentUser value. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Where is CurrentUser? And why are you creating 2 factories called Data?

Comment: I actually just put the full context in there to help visualize the structure, but I realize that may have been more confusing to do so. They are all under one large factory. I will post a plunk since I think the snippets may have done more harm than good.

Answer (score 0):

You don't demonstrate where you are declaring `CurrentUser` (eg `var CurrentUser;`) (I couldnt see it).

I trust you are not using a global variable (evil).

Also it is unclear where you are invoking these factory methods that are accessing CurrentUser. You are assigning CurrentUser inside the `Data.getCurrentUser` invocation in your controller. Assuming you have declared CurrentUser outside that function somewhere, it will not be assigned until the asynchronous request has completed. I'd suggest refactoring your method `updateAppointment` to receive the `CurrentUser` parameter instead of relying on outside scope.

Comment: [Here is a plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/s4ldUjcnkamSc3lLEILd). That should help, but I'm beginning to realize what may have happened...

Comment: i'm trying to do the same thing - using rest api to get current user id and current user name from sharepoint 2013. how were you able to resolve your issue